# Matrix that gives the inverse of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

If I had the set of all matrices that have inverse (not sure if special $SL_n$ or general linear group $GL_n$). If I consider the transformation $T:GL_n \to GL_n$ defined as $T(m)=m^{-1}$. I ask is this $T$ capable of be represented as a linear transformation and as a matrix. It appears though it is not possible because if we had a $n$ by $n$ matrix $A$ then $A[T]=A^{-1}$ but this implies $A^{-1}A[T]=A^{-1}A^{-1}$ or $[T]=(A^{-1})^2$ but we see that not all of $GL_n$'s squares are equal hence there is no inverse linear transformation. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: It is easier: $T(2A) = \frac12 T(A)$, thus not linear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, your map $T$ is not linear, for the inverse of $I + I$ is not $I + I$ but rather $\frac{1}{2} I$.

Your reasoning, however, seems muddled to me; it's not clear what $A[T]$ is supposed to denote. Note that the matrix for the transformtion $T$ would have to be an $n^2 \times n^2$ matrix, operating on the matrix $A$ by expressing $A$ in the standard basis, i.e., writing out $A$'s elements in a long long column vector (and similarly converting $T(A)$, another column vector of length $n^2$, back into matrix form).

It's probably easiest to verify that this doesn't work by looking at the case $n = 1$, where everything is very very simple. I leave it to you to try that.

**Post-comment addition**

OP wrote: "Also $T$ was the abstract transformation defined by $T(m) \to m^{−1}$. $[T]$ was used to represent the transformation with respect to a chosen basis as a matrix."

Let's look at the $2 \times 2$ case. A basis for the space of $2 \times 2$ matrices consists of the four matrices
$$
E_{11} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\\
E_{12} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\\
E_{21} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\\
E_{22} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
The matrix 
$$
M = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}
$$
can be expressed in this basis as $M = a E_{11} + b E_{12} + c E_{21} + d E_{22}$, i.e., in this basis, the representation of $M$ is the 4-vector
$$
\begin{bmatrix} a & b & c & d \end{bmatrix}
$$
and so the matrix for your transformation $T$ (which you've called $[T]$) will have to be a $4 \times 4$ matrix. That means that the expression $A[T]$ doesn't make sense, because $A$ is $2 \times 2$ and $[T]$ is $4 \times 4$.

==================

Let me make one other observation: in general, you can only hope to define a linear transformation on a *vector space*, which must have an addition operation defined on it and a scalar multiple operation, and they must satisfy the axioms of a vector space.

The set $GL(n)$ of $n \times n$ invertible matrices lacks both of these things. There's an addition operation on the set of *all* $n \times n$ matrices, but its restriction to $GL(n)$ does not produce values in $GL(n)$ in general. (People sometimes say "$GL(n)$ is not closed under addition.") As an example, but $I$ and $-I$ are in $GL(n)$, but their sum is not.

In short: the space on which you were hoping to define a linear transformation isn't even a vector space, so you were bound to run into troubles.

Comment: Yes I had thought of the 1 by 1 matrix that has inverse as an interesting case or a concrete personification of what I asked.

Comment: Also $T$ was the abstract transformation defined by $T(m) \to m^{-1} $.  $[T]$ was used to represent the transformation with respect to a chosen basis as a matrix.

Comment: Also I don't see the line of reasoning being muddled related to the answer? It seems to me if we assume there was a linear transformation $[T]$ it's consequence would lead to the implication that all invertable matrices' squares are equal. I don's see how $n^2 \times n^2$ is related? Sorry if I do not understand something? Also if there is area that I am missing and you can point me in area to review it would help. I want to understand about extending dimension for achieving certain things it is interesting topic, even if in case like this it still fails. Thanks.

Comment: See my additional comments in the answer.

Comment: Hmm this makes it a lot more clear. I still have to think about the different aspects but thanks. I guess what seems strange is in the $2 \times 2$ the standard basis $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$. The basis vectors themselves and the vectors they span are all $\Bbb R^2$. While here the basis vectors are $\Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb R^2$ while they span $\Bbb R^4$ for $E_{ij}$. It seems that in $\Bbb R^4$ then inner product corresponds with the standard inner product. I will have to look to see initially where I went astray.

Comment: That's the standard basis for $\mathbb R^2$, but not for $M_{22}$. Keeping your vector spaces separate in your head is critical. :)